# how to get Access token from open authentication in Cross Domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

i am trying open authentication first time in mvc-web-api4 . i have hosted my services in services.domain.com , and front end (UI) is in test.domain.com .

in front end i will call the service to login from facebook. after successful login i will get the access token in services.domain.com . but my code is in test.domain.com.

after redirection from facebook . i am getting access token in service.bubblesbuy.com , but i need that access token in test.domain.com.

here are the steps i followed

```
$.ajax({
    url: "services.domain.com/api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true",
    success: function (data) { 
    //after successful 
    }
```

after successful , i will get providers , here is the output

```
[     
{
"Name": "Facebook",
"Url": "/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=services.domain.com&state=bzDUygFiUw-jOYHCYaDPT8iawAjq1ejd0hmkVPZTwjk1",
"State": "bzDUygFiUw-jOYHCYaDPT8iawAjq1ejd0hmkVPZTwjk1"
}
]
```

i will pass Url to my service

```
services.domain.com//api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=services.domain.com&state=bzDUygFiUw-jOYHCYaDPT8iawAjq1ejd0hmkVPZTwjk1",
"State": "bzDUygFiUw-jOYHCYaDPT8iawAjq1ejd0hmkVPZTwjk1
```

i am getting the access token in

```
services.domain.com/#access_token= Hu2B5WmmZLy8TfJ3RqRsVnQDfDcHSiVCMliWrS554PpU-i_LQzdMggJgXClsf-ZtYXRDxxct7m3frZxYR0MKLxNWHwH1gXxi7Y-HUbWjyB9QvBJMwifFCVMnt7BOOlKjJPEAhdOY7ZgRB-vURBH-hHT6wFSXJvvpYpZ0fziX0DgKrLIqUj8&token_type=bearer&expires_in=1209600&state=24HUa-Upzo-_Xh2j0CkAx5TVPdoirvNrGktpg5H5Ifg1
```

but i need to access that token in test.domain.com (front end where my all html page is there )

please help me how to get that access token in test.domain.com (in front end )